# iOS Today Extension transparent background color

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I'm trying to change the background for the today widget to be transparent without the blurry effect but I can't figure out how to do that. Has anyone been able to change the background for the widget? Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: Did you specifically need to modify the blurring-background effect, or did you want to paint a color across the background of the widget?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change the widget background color and you cannot remove blur effect